# Why does Debug.print differentiate between Boolean and Integer?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm assuming that in vba the type `Boolean` is just a 16 bit integer. So why and how does `Debug.Print` differentiate between the two?

```
Debug.Print -1 = True
Debug.Print -1
Debug.Print True
```

Will output:

```
True
-1  
True
```

Answer (score 6):

Line 1 evaluates to (if -1 equals true) then print true else print false

Line 2 evaluates to print -1 (as you asked)

Line 3 evaluates to print true (as you asked)

-1 is true and 0 is false in VBA

Answer (score 3):

You could also assume that a string is an array of bytes, or that a 16-bit integer is a series of 0's and 1's.

The answer is *because VBA as a language provides an abstraction for Boolean values*.

That's all there is to it: it *knows* and *defines* that `True` and `False` are `Boolean` literals; their respective underlying values are nothing but plumbing to make it work: `False` maps to `0`, and any non-zero value converts to `True`, with `-1` being returned for Boolean-to-numeric conversions.

IOW, this isn't about `Debug.Print`, it's about VBA's type system.

Answer (score 3):

Boolean variables are stored as 16-bit (2-byte) numbers, but they can only be True or False.

> When other numeric types are converted to Boolean values, 0 becomes
>   False and all other values become True.
>   When Boolean values are converted to other data types, False becomes 0 and True becomes -1.

On your first Debug.Print you evaluate an expression (-1 = True) which is True.

The second prints an Integer.

The third prints a Boolean.

[Boolean Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/boolean-data-type)